# Building/Waiting for parent job Latest version

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, build, pipeline

We have maven projects on git with structure of

```
--
  pro-A
  --
    pro-B
    --
      pro-C
      pro-D
      --
        pro-E
```

These are all project with their own repo in git and their own build-pipeline in jenkins with stages as follows

```
build  -- deploy to TEST -- run tests -- (manual tigger) deploy to QA
```

every build gets deployed to maven repo with jenkins build number appended to it and merge to release branch from master and tag with the new version number: e.g. 1.0.9-649

So, pro-A is parent of all projects, pro-B only depends on pro-A, pro-C and pro-D are at the same level they don't depend on each other but have dependency on pro-B, pro-E have dependency on all others pro-A,B,C,D

When a change is pushed gitlab triggers a build for the respective project. Now the problem is that when, say A and D changes and Ds build is triggered before a there is a good chance that the build fails as it depends on the newer code of A.

My question is, is it possible to pause the Ds build until A finishes building?

I was thinking something like in pre-step of D try to see if latest commit has a later timestamp than the release branch then trigger a build on parent, but don't know how?

Comment: Reminds me of https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin. It should be possible to make a job depends on another.

Comment: We already use "Build Pipeline", as I have mentioned mirroring the dependency requirement to build-pipeline gets very messy quickly, that's why I am looking an alternative way of triggering dependency build and wait for it to finish

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to pause D's build until A finishes. You will have to install: **"Parametrized Trigger Plugin"**. Once installed, go to D's configuration. Under Build, Add build step, select **"Trigger/Call builds on other projects"**.

After that put **"A"** in **"Projects to build"** and then check **"Block until the triggered projects finish their builds"**. Save the configuration.

This should fulfill your requirement.