# How can I solve in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When I trigger(parameterized build, I am selecting multiple slaves) one single job on multiple slaves with 3 executors per slaves. On first slave build success but 2nd , 3rd and so on waiting for executors and all jobs in queue.

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying. You have one build, where you select multiple slaves when starting it (which doesn't seem to make sense), yet multiple builds are queued? If they're builds of the same job, then you need to enable "Execute concurrent builds if necessary".

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like this:              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483322/building-waiting-for-parent-job-latest-version/27495289#27495289

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Multi-Configuration project.
Create a project and what are you looking for is the "Configuration Matrix".
You can find your answer here.
[Jenkins and multi-configuration (matrix) jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515730/jenkins-and-multi-configuration-matrix-jobs)

Comment: This seems unrelated to executor exhaustion, or builds remaining in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

What you need (you need to rewrite it to be clearer) will be solved using a combination of [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) and [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin).